# How configure SystemJS with Auth0?

Tags: javascript, npm, angular, systemjs

I tried configure SystemJS for Auth0 (angular2-jwt) and Angular 2.0.0-beta.6 but always I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/angular2/http 404 (Not Found)fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1068(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1649lib$es6$promise$$internal$$initializePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:515lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise @ angular2-polyfills.js:806(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1648(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2669(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3233(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3500(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4116(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4324(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4564(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:326Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2/http(…)
```

**SystemJS:**

```
<script>
    //configure system loader
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-jwt': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      },
      map: {
        'angular2-jwt': 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'
      }
    });
  </script>
```

In addition, I have read the [SystemJS documentation](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md) but I am not sure about how to fix this issue.

Comment: Show the other `<script>` tags, the ones with `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not importing `angular2/http` script along the others:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/http.js"></script> <!-- add this -->
```

Don't forget to bootstrap it, or else you'll get:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! (AppComponent -> Http)
>   
> ...
>   
> Error: DI Exception ...

Bootstrap it:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Comment: If using ES5: `ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent, [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]);`

Comment: With `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/http.js"></script>` it works!